# How to send jsonfile in api Request

Tags: java, json, spring, api

I am facing an issue while sending the json file in request for RestController, Please check the details below

I have a json file , let say test.json

```
{
    "PolicyNumber": "123",
    "Type": "Test",
    "Tenture": "10",
    "SDate": "10-July-2016",
    "HName": "Test User",
    "Age": "10"
}
```

I want to send the test.json file postman
[image]

**TestController**

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    
    @PostMapping(value="/uploadJsonFile", consumes= {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE},
             produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE} )
    
    public ResponseEntity<String> uplaodFile(@RequestPart MultipartFile file){
        
        System.out.println("Original File Name :- "+file.getOriginalFilename());
        System.out.println("File type :- "+file.getName());
        System.out.println("File Size :- "+file.getSize()); 
        System.out.println("Content Type :- "+file.getContentType());
        //Validation file is empty
        if(file.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("File is Empty Insert Data"); 
        }
        
        if(!file.getContentType().equals("application/json")) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("only json file content"); 
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Upload File Sucessfully"); 
    }
}
```

I have tried couple of ways like below
In method, if I used `@RequestBody` ,file is comes as null and when I used `@ResponseBody` or `@RequestPart` postman giving `400 bad request`  error message

I also tried to used `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping(value="/uploadJsonFile", method= RequestMethod.POST` but no luck

**Pom.xml file**

```
<properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <spring.version>4.3.26.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <springsecurity.version>4.2.15.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
        <jcl.slf4j.version>1.7.30</jcl.slf4j.version>
    </properties>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>TestWebApp</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

**Spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.test.api" />
    <context:annotation-config />
 
    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:application.properties" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"
        location="/resources/" />
        
 <mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator"/> 
 
        <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:message" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    
     
    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
        <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
        <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
</beans>
```

Note:- I have a very big json file, so can not send it as json data, need to send the json file only

Really Appriciate any help here

Comment: Try Refer 1 - https://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-tutorials/spring-mvc-file-upload-restful-web-service-example

Refer 2 - https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-rest/multipart-upload-download-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would like to add my answer in case anyone who also faces a similar issue can use it.
TestController

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    
    @PostMapping("/uploadJsonFile")    
    public ResponseEntity<String> uplaodFile(@RequestParam("file") final MultipartFile file){
        
        System.out.println("Original File Name :- "+file.getOriginalFilename());
        System.out.println("File type :- "+file.getName());
        System.out.println("File Size :- "+file.getSize()); 
        System.out.println("Content Type :- "+file.getContentType());
        //Validation file is empty
        if(file.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("File is Empty Insert Data"); 
        }
        
        if(!file.getContentType().equals("application/json")) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("only json file content"); 
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Upload File Sucessfully"); 
    }
}
```

Postman request

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to modify the key name on your request?
In your code, you named 'file' to your MultipartFile, but in postman you named 'type' for your key text.
Try to name 'file' instead of 'type'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: that was just a typo, that's not the issue